# Need to animate an image to move away from cursor postion on each mouseover?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mouseover

I'm trying to animate an image of a box by changing it's position on mouseover.

I can get it to move once but I need to set it up so that it moves everytime someone mouses over the image. I want to make the users 'chase' the box around the screen.

Preferably the animation would loop so that a user can never catch the image ?

Here is [an example of what I have so far](http://aoifeodwyer.com/box/), and below is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#img').mouseover(function() {
        $(this).animate({
            left: '500px'
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks a million!

Comment: Oh here's the final version: http://ccad.aoifeodwyer.com/truth/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/atNva/). It covers basics I guess.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#img').mouseover(function() {
        var dWidth = $(document).width() - 100, // 100 = image width
            dHeight = $(document).height() - 100, // 100 = image height
            nextX = Math.floor(Math.random() * dWidth),
            nextY = Math.floor(Math.random() * dHeight);
        $(this).animate({ left: nextX + 'px', top: nextY + 'px' });
    });
});
```

Comment: ... that shouldn't have entertained me for as long as it did.

Comment: This fiddle will make it fly back to where it was originally: http://jsfiddle.net/atNva/196/