# How to make a div which escapes from mouse cursor randomly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I tried to find a code that makes a div escaping from the cursor randomly but I couldn't find any. Maybe I don't know how to search, maybe it's so easy but my English is not good enough to solve that situation.

I want a div which escapes from cursor randomly in a parent div, can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please add the code which you have tried.

Comment: I don't have any code to make this, because I'm a newbie and generally I'm making the stuff with manipulating the codes which I find. But in this situation, I couldn't find any :(

Comment: You need to describe your issue better. What do you mean by a div escaping from the mouse cursor randomly? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Hmm sorry for my English. When mouse is getting over a div, it should be move to another position. Think about a button you cannot catch and push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="touchMeNot"></div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.touchMeNot').on('mouseenter',function(e){
    var maxX = $(window).width() - $(this).width();
    var maxY = $(window).height() - $(this).height();
    $(this).css({
        'left':getRandomInt(0, maxX),
        'top':getRandomInt(0, maxY)
    });
});
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

**CSS**

```
.touchMeNot{
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/xgjfvjmp/1/).

**Update**

This is done in order to avoid the box going out of the window.

```
var maxX = $(window).width() - $(this).width();
var maxY = $(window).height() - $(this).height();
```

We can generalize by using the div width in the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

Randomized but also *animated* :

```
$("#move").mouseenter(function () {

    $(this).animate({
        top: Math.random() * 300
    }, 100);
    $(this).animate({
        left: Math.random() * 300
    }, 100);

});
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1n4a56qm/)
Cheers :D

Comment: Hey thank you! That's it! An additonal question;

How can I stuck this animation into a parent div?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand. Can you please rephrase? :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/50zmxw7y/

I want it only in the grey area, it shouldn't run outside that div!

Comment: Sorry for my English :)

Comment: [Here you go](http://jsfiddle.net/50zmxw7y/1/) :) Sry for the late reply though :)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help:

HTML

```
<div id="runner">
</div>
```

CSS

```
#runner {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
}
```

JS

```
$("#runner").on('mouseover', function(){
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var goX = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    var goY = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -1 : 1;
    $(this).css('top', offset.top + 20 * goY);
    $(this).css('left', offset.left + 20 * goX);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3hLp6myj/

Comment: Hey Sargon!

That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have one more question @Sargon.

Comment: When I'm trying to do, it escapes out from the div which I want to make all action inside of it. https://jsfiddle.net/50zmxw7y/

Comment: Just check that its new width / height is not more then max value which is size of your container. If it is more then max value or less then min, just change the sign, so it will move in opposite direction =)

Comment: Oh, I tried it but it does not make any sense... Still image goes out from the div but also out from the screen sometimes... :(

Comment: Sorry, do not have much time to clean this up, but here is the POC :)
https://jsfiddle.net/3hLp6myj/1/

Comment: And here is one more change:
https://jsfiddle.net/3hLp6myj/2/
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

We've done this as a joke not too long ago, it's quite simple:

```
$('button').hover(function() {
    $(this).text("Can't touch this!");
    $(this).css('top', Math.random()*500 + 'px').css('left', Math.random()*600 + 'px');
});
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrupausan/c8gL6wgb/)

Answer (score -1):

This has been answered in another question, here is the example that was created http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/atNva/ . I believe this is what you was after correct?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#img').mouseover(function() {
        var dWidth = $(document).width() - 100, // 100 = image width
            dHeight = $(document).height() - 100, // 100 = image height
            nextX = Math.floor(Math.random() * dWidth),
            nextY = Math.floor(Math.random() * dHeight);
        $(this).animate({ left: nextX + 'px', top: nextY + 'px' });
    });
});
```

Here is the other question: [Need to animate an image to move away from cursor postion on each mouseover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437682/need-to-animate-an-image-to-move-away-from-cursor-postion-on-each-mouseover)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey it will be a joke site to someone's birthday, what kind of an abuse you're talking about...

Comment: No I miss read your question, I thought you wanted to move the mouse pointer. I edited the answer.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! That's what I was searching for! Cool man, peace out!